# Syntax: In F# how to return a value from a member of a discriminated union?

Tags: f#, discriminated-union

With the following code:

```
type ContactDetail = { Name: string; Content: string; Text: string }
type Internet      = { Name: string; Content: string; Text: string }
type PhoneNumber   = { Name: string; Content: string; Text: string }
type Address       = { Name: string; Content: string; Text: string }

    module FrontOffice =    
        type Details =
            | ContactDetail of ContactDetail * Id: Guid
            | Internet      of Internet   * Id: Guid
            | PhoneNumber   of PhoneNumber   * Id: Guid
            | Address       of Address  * Id: Guid
            
          
            member this.name = 
                match this with
                | ContactDetail(_, id)
                | Internet(_, id) 
                | PhoneNumber(_, id) 
                | Address(_, id) -> ???????????????????
```

I need the extension method, this.name, to return the Name property on the match.  How is this done?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how:

```
type ContactDetail = { Name: string; Content: string; Text: string }
type Internet      = { Name: string; Content: string; Text: string }
type PhoneNumber   = { Name: string; Content: string; Text: string }
type Address       = { Name: string; Content: string; Text: string }

module FrontOffice =

    type Details =
        | ContactDetail of ContactDetail * Id: Guid
        | Internet      of Internet   * Id: Guid
        | PhoneNumber   of PhoneNumber   * Id: Guid
        | Address       of Address  * Id: Guid
        
        member this.name = 
            match this with
            | ContactDetail (cd, _) -> cd.Name
            | Internet (i, _) -> i.Name
            | PhoneNumber (pn, _) -> pn.Name
            | Address (a, _) -> a.Name

    let sample () =
        let contactDetail = { ContactDetail.Name = "myname"; Content = "mycontent"; Text = "mytext" }
        let details: Details = ContactDetail (contactDetail, Guid.NewGuid ())
        printfn "%A" details
        // ContactDetail ({Name = "myname"; Content = "mycontent"; Text = "mytext";},1a25bcdd-76b0-4cb3-8a34-72872d2542c2)
        printfn "The name is %s" details.name
        // The name is myname
```

Comment: I would not structure data in this way, but that would be material for another question.

Comment: Thank you very much sir. Its answers like this that are really helping me get a grip on this stuff--studying the books somehow misses real-life work. As to restructuring the data, I would really like to move the Id property into ContactDetail, etc.

Comment: Talking about books, have you seen the [F# for fun and profit](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/) web site? Worth far more than any book I've come across. It is actually the equivalent of a book, just on web pages. And you can download it as a PDF.

Comment: Adding on to what @BentTranberg said, the author of the site he mentioned wrote a book titled: "Domain Modeling Made Functional: Tackle Software Complexity with Domain-Driven Design and F#".  It is a very good resource related to modelling your data.